# yup validation hierarchy issue (formik vs react-hook-form with yupResolver)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working on converting forms from Formik over to React Hook Form. `yup` is the validator in both cases. However I've noticed that despite leaving the validation schema in tact, there seems to be some sort of hierarchy mismatch between Formik and RHF.

I noticed for instance that for `min`, `max`, `required`, originally in that order, validation was working correctly with Formik, but I had to invoke `required` before `min` & `max` in order for the correct validation message to trigger on an input. That fix was self-explanatory enough.

But some of these are tricky. For instance:

```
    dob: yup.date().when([], (schema: yup.DateSchema) => {
      return boolCheck1 && boolCheck2
        ? yup.string()
        : schema
            .min(
              moment.utc().add(1, 'day').subtract(126, 'years').toDate(),
              'an error message'
            )
            .max(
              moment.utc().subtract(15, 'years').toDate(),
              'another error message'
            )
            .transform((_, originalValue) => {
              const date = moment.utc(originalValue, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
              return date.isValid()
                ? date.startOf('day').toDate()
                : new Date('');
            })
            .typeError('A valid date is required (MM/DD/YYYY)')
            .required('Please enter a valid date');
   })
```

It seems that regardless of where I am placing the `required` check, the one that is triggered is `typeError` ("A valid date is required (MM/DD/YYYY)"). Basically, if a user touches and blurs this input field without having typed anything, it should trigger the `required` message ("Please enter a valid date".) Only when a user types something that does not pass the `typeError` check should the typeError message appear.

This was working previously with Formik. However, now, I'm using React Hook Form as such:

```
  const rhfMethods = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onTouched',
  });
```

The only difference really is that now the `yupResolver` is being used (without which I get a typescript error.)

If anyone could shed any light on this that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Nvm, looks like a similar question had already been asked and [answered](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/971#issuecomment-658746587).

While that definitely helped shed light on the issue (`''` is still a string type, not simply no data), what helped me solve this was [this addendum](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/971#issuecomment-961402894).

I still needed the initial `''` to be a valid input type, so instead of returning an `Invalid Date` (`new Date('')`) in the else case, I just needed to return `undefined`.

Final fix:

```
    dob: yup.date().when([], (schema: yup.DateSchema) => {
      return boolCheck1 && boolCheck2
        ? yup.string()
        : schema
            .min(
              moment.utc().add(1, 'day').subtract(126, 'years').toDate(),
              'an error message'
            )
            .max(
              moment.utc().subtract(15, 'years').toDate(),
              'another error message'
            )
            .transform((_, originalValue) => {
              const date: moment.Moment = moment.utc(
                originalValue,
                'MM/DD/YYYY'
              );
              return date.isValid() ? date.startOf('day').toDate() : undefined;
            })
            .typeError('A valid date is required (MM/DD/YYYY)')
            .required('Please enter a valid date');
   })
```

(To be fair... I tried testing on the UI and there was no instance where this `.typeError` was ever triggered (even with Formik) since every allowable input instance (only numbers can be typed and they're auto-formatted to dates) was already being checked by the other tests... I think I could safely remove that `typeError` check altogether lol.)